# I cannot boot Windows 7 after I installed Ubuntu on a partition

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, windows

I installed Ubuntu and now I can't access Windows 7. When it boots it shows Ubuntu and Windows 7. I can launch Ubuntu, but when I try to launch Windows it goes to the Windows loading logo and stays there forever. I've ran boot repair and Windows repair, neither have worked. I cannot access my backup either.
EDIT: I tried using system recovery from windows boot and boot repair in ubuntu. Im not super sure what boot repair it was, I just ran the program and it instructed me through terminal. Ubuntu works fine it is on a partition, windows loads but stays at the starting windows screen. It shows up as an option for boot, but does not complete the boot.

Comment: Grub only boots working Windows, so normally your Windows fixes should work. Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Comment: Please run the [Boot Repair utility](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) and select the "Create BootInfo Summary" option. (*DO NOT* click "Recommended Repair," at least not yet!) When asked whether to upload the report, click "Yes," and then post the URL provided here. This will give us more details about your configuration, which is required to base an answer on more than guesswork.

Comment: I do that and there is no link, just paste2.org without anything after

Comment: @J.Doe: It appears that functionality broke recently. You can still save the Boot-Info summary to a file and upload it to [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/).

Answer (score 0):

This can be caused by many totally different problems. But one thing you can try (if you haven't already tried, "boot repair" and "windows repair" is not very precise) is repairing your Windows bootloader with a Windows 7 repair disk or live CD or USB. Do the following:

- Boot from your live CD or whatever you got.
- Go to repair, but do not use "Startup Repair". Instead open the Windows command prompt
- Type the following:`bootrec.exe /fixmbr` and then press Enter
- Type the following:`bootrec.exe /fixboot` and then press Enter

When you reboot now you should see your Windows bootloader again. Look if you can boot now.

Then, regardless of whether it works or not, repair your GRUB bootloader

- Boot from an Ubuntu Live CD or USB and use "Load Ubuntu without install"
- Install boot-repair
- Repair GRUB with it. Guide is here -> https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

This **could** work.

If not the fastest and simplest solution is to access your most important Windows files via your freshly installed Linux or a Live USB/CD and do a backup to wherever you want. **Then wipe everything and try installing it all again.** Be more careful this time.